# Webcon IIS HTTP 500.19 Error

Tags: iis, webcon

I've completed a clean install of Webcon (2019.1.4.250) on Sharepoint (2016), everything went smooth, but when I try to open any Webcon page I get an error:
[image: error]

I've alread reinstalled Webcon and I gave all required rights to the IIS, but it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea what else I can do to resolve that error?

Comment: You probably missed an out-of-band component like URL Rewrite module. Check the web.config file as it contains the hint.